# Python - getting io.BufferedRandom but should be a file object

Tags: python, csv, file-io, zip

I have a list of URLS. I iterate over them, and for each URL I download each .zip file and save it. Then, I need to put this file into a dictionary, but I want to skip all the lines starting with `#`. (I solved a similar problem by putting a `filter` over the file, but I am not able to use that approach here.) Here is my code:

```
1. for link in urls:
2.        affy_reader = {}
3. 
4.        # get_data() downloads the file, saves it as a .csv.zip, and
5.        # returns a pointer to the file.
6.
7.        n = get_data(link)
8.        z = zipfile.ZipFile(n)
9.
10.       # only want the .csv from the archive
11.       for name in z.namelist():
12.            if '.csv' in name:  
13.                print('Writing - ' +name)
14.                fp = open(name, 'wb+')  
15.                fp.write(z.read(name)) 
16.                fp.close()
17.
18.                with(open(fp, 'r')) as f:                  # open file A to read only
19.                   with(open('temp.txt', 'w+')) as file_p: # open file B to read AND write
20.                        for row in f:
21.                            if not row.startswith('#'):
22.                                file_p.write(row)
23.                   file_p.close()
26.                   affy_reader = csv.DictReader(fd,
27.                                                delimiter='\t',
28.                                                fieldnames=affy_column_headers)
30.                   for x in affy_reader:
31.                       print(x)
```

As you can see, on line #18 I try to open the original file A, write out only the rows I want to another file B, then try load B into the `DictReader`. Here is the the error I get back:

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.BufferedRandom name='HG-U133A.na33.annot.csv'>
```

So what I get back from `fp = open(name, 'wb+')` looks like a string buffer, not a file. However, [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says that I should be getting a `file object` back from `open()`. So how do I get this buffer into a file? Or, better yet, am I just missing some step here? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is just a mistake with the transfer of code from your program to here, but on line 16 I think you want to call `fp.close()` rather than simply include an empty reference to the function.

Comment: It was like that in my source also. I changed it to `fp.close()` but get the same result from running my program. Strange that the interpreter wouldnt complain that I need `()`...

Comment: The point of using the context manager (with statement) is that it closes the file itself. On line 26, where does fd come from?

Comment: Edit: I think it's a typo for fp. If it is, you closed fp. It's invalid when you try to use it.

Comment: It is a typo, you are right. And I do close fp, but then I open it again on line #18...don't I? I think I do anyway.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) _"After calling f.close(), attempts to use the file object will automatically fail."_ Isn't that the reason for your `open` to fail? Try to re-open by name `open(name, ...)`instead.